# Django CSRF fails when used in an extended page

Tags: django

All pages are extended from a base template.
There is a form in the base template and the form has the CSRF tag. When submitting the form while on home page, all works fine. However for all other pages (also extended from same base template) the submit fails with the following error: 
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Inspecting the page with Firebug, the hidden input field that holds the CSRF token is missing.

Comment: i suppose you already did like Srikar said on first answer (or it won't even work on the base template) so can you please tell us more about the extended pages? maybe some code? i've always worked with form on base template and pages extending it, and never had your issue (and didn's setup anything particular)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this -

1. In settings modify - `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ('django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware')`
2. Next to any form in your templates, put this - `<form method="post" class="login_form" name="frmlogin">{% csrf_token %}`

This would solve your problem...

Comment: I already have both. the {% csrf_token %} tag is in the base template. This works only on the home page and not on other pages, all extended from the base template.

Comment: try putting in `{% csrf_token %}` in the derived templates to be sure that is the problem then we ca see what to do about it...